# Selenium webscraping, open chrome fail

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to scrape from a website.
I am trying to open a url with chromedriver through a script. It does open chrome but it does not insert the url. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/***/Downloads/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'https://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/lnacademic/?verb=sf&amp;sfi=AC00NBGenSrch'
browser.get(url)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***/Downloads/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    browser.get(url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"31081.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64)
```

What can I do so that it inserts the url?

Comment: I advice you to check which chrome-drive you are using and if are fully compatible with your chrome version; in any case I added chromedrive.exe to the Windows path system instead to specify the path in the code and it solved me many problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure the cause of the error, but I would definitely suggest downloading a newer version of `chromedriver`

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

I'd also suggest updating selenium(from terminal): `pip install -U pip selenium`

Answer (score 0):

Chromedriver 2.9 version is quite outdated.

Try to download latest `chromedriver` version from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/)

Note that despite of order on [releases list page](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) actual order of releases looks like

- 2.0
- 2.1

  ...
- 2.9
- 2.10

  ...
- 2.32